# Text that is conditional on date

Tags: templating

I have set up a structure that allows me to display events with some information.  I'd like to know if there's a way that I can set a date that will automatically change certain  it's a text from being future tense to be in present tense during the event and past tense after the event i.e.  I'll be, I am, I was.

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this. I'm assuming the events have `eventStart` and `eventEnd` date variables, and I'm here comparing the dates with the built in `now` variable on the format year-month-hour-minute:

```
{# When eventStart is bigger than "now", the event is in the future #}
{% if event.eventStart|date('YmdHi') > now|date('YmdHi') %}
  I will attend this event!

{# When eventStart is in the past, and eventEnd is in the future, the event is ongoing #}
{% elseif event.eventStart|date('YmdHi') <= now|date('YmdHi') and event.eventEnd|date('YmdHi') > now|date('YmdHi') %}
  I am at this event RIGHT NOW!

{# When none of the above, the event is in the past #}
{% else %}
  I was at this event
{% endif %}
```

Depending on your use, you could build on this to create a variable for "past/present/future" or similiar. To be even more sure on your validation, the last `endif` could also specifically test that the `endDate` is in the past, instead of just being a catch-all `else`.